# Unknown format image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to upload an image from camera using image picker and firebase storage but still have this problem: when I upload the image, I get an "unknown format" of image. Here is the problem - can you help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I expect to see file format jpg or png but it shows unknown file

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use this code to convert any types of file in png formate

```
List<int> imageBytes = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();
img.Image image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes))!;

// Convert the image to PNG format
List<int> pngBytes = img.encodePng(image);
```